# Upload part of a video files to server

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to make a webpage where you can upload a video to the server (let say using a File Input HTML TAG). I would like to know if it's possible in ANY languages to upload only small parts of the video files without uploading the whole file first and then splitting the file.

Let me give you an example of what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to create a service where one upload a long & big video file and I give them 10 samples segment of the video file as a result.

Let say I have a 1 hours long & /1 Gig size video (avi) file.

I would like to get a sample of 10 segments of 1 minutes spread across the entire file uploaded to the server.

I know that I could upload the whole file and then split it but uploading a 1G file would be way long for the user.

I want to know if upfront there is a way to choose what part of the file need to be uploaded so I could upload only specific segments and then re-construct the files to make them readable.

I know this is more of a subjective question and it may not be well fitted for Stack Overflow but I really need to figure out how to do that.

Comment: it depends on the codec, but sometimes you can just crop the file, drop it in a new container, and ittl work. you can do that for js Files using the file.slice() method to get a new Blob with part of the file data

Comment: @dandavis: Exactly that's what I want to do but can this be done with a video file? Will I be able to "reconstruct" the file afterward to make it readable?

Comment: i would go so far as to say "usually", but it's complicated. note how the <video> tag uses http RANGE headers to fetch middle chunks of a large video. this means it's possible, but you might need to know exactly where to crop, and that information is difficult to determine from javascript at this time. i would try something naive like grabbing a 2mb chunk and POSTing the blob to my server. there are command-line tools that can likely recover the video from the blob dump and fix it into a valid file.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, this isn't doable.  @dandavis is right... some containers and codecs allow you to arbitrarily split (like MPEG-2).  Many however don't (MP4), and without the container header you won't be getting very far.

Unless you plan to re-implement all of FFmpeg into JavaScript, you're better off waiting for that upload to finish.